# What are these Cocoons/Seeds?

Tags: species-identification

I have found these thingies in my institute at Tiruchchirapalli in India. I have no idea what they are:

[image]

[image]

Can someone tell me what they are, exactly?

Comment: Sorry if the picture isn't clear, the thingy must have been eroded a bit.

Comment: It's difficult to get an idea of how large/small this is, given the provided images.

Comment: @Charles It's about 1 cm across. I took a closeup shot for more accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

They look like seeds from palm trees. It reminds me of seeds from Phoenix canariensis which I once planted. However, since this particular species is not native to India, they could be seeds from another [Phoenix palm species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_(plant)). Do you have Phoenix palm species in your area in India?

Comment: We have lots of palm trees around here, since it's the tropics

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you validate it with pictures? I tried googling, but wasn't satisfied.

Comment: I can't tell exactly, sorry. You probably know more about palm trees than I do (I live in the Netherlands where no native palm trees grow). But it did remind me of _Phoenix canariensis_ [seeds](https://www.amazon.co.uk/canary-tree-Phoenix-canariensis-seeds/dp/B004S0AXBO). So I hoped you would know which relative palm species would be at your institute. Maybe you should plant them and see what comes out of it?